# How to get the distance between two objects in the game engine?

Tags: python, game-engine

So far I could only find the method to get the current position of the objects. I think there is a method that returns the distance between them.

Comment: I make BGE tutorials on my channel, and I have this exact solution, scripts, and .blend file in the description. Just keep watching through the video, I believe I show you how 3 minutes through. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2BL9AxORec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you plan on telling blender which two objects. Assuming they are both selected.

```
import bpy
from math import sqrt

def get_distance():
    """
    return: float. Distance of the two objects
    Must select two objects
    """
    l = []  # we store the loacation vector of each object
    for item in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        l.append(item.location)

    distance = sqrt( (l[0][0] - l[1][0])**2 + (l[0][1] - l[1][1])**2 + (l[0][2] - l[1][2])**2)
    print(distance)  # print distance to console, DEBUG
    return distance

get_distance()
```

Comment: I think the OP means in the BGE.

Comment: How do I see the output of print in that part of the blender visualize?

Comment: in the console, aka terminal/cmd. You need to start blender form the console though as well

Comment: @Guilherme If you choose to mark this as accepted, please rephrase your question to correlate with it as this does not apply to the bge. Also, use of `bpy` in the bge is discouraged.

Comment: This answer isn't the game engine.

Comment: Either one of the other answers provided is the correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `mathutils.Vector` locations

```
import bge

scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
# the object the sensor is connected to
owner = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner
# the other object you want to get the distance to
obj2 = scene.objects['obj_name']
length = (owner.worldPosition - obj2.worldPosition).length

print(length)
```

This allows for easier manipulation, so for example if you only want to measure distance on a map (without taking altitude into account) you can do.

```
length = (owner.worldPosition.xy - obj2.worldPosition.xy).length
```

Answer (score 5):

That would be [`getDistanceTo`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.getDistanceTo). It will calculate and return the distance between two objects *from* their origins.

```
import bge

scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
# the object the sensor is connected to
owner = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner
# the other object you want to get the distance to
obj2 = scene.objects['obj_name']
length = owner.getDistanceTo(obj2)

print(length)
```