# How to change objects texture using python in BGE?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

**What i want to do:**

If **player/ avatar** is close to an object, objects texture changes to a higher rez one/ *object changes material*.

- How to get distance between two objects using script?
- How to apply/change texture to an object using script?

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to write python code, you can change the material with level of detail (LOD)

[image]

Create different objects (or duplicate the same mesh Shift-D if don't want lower polygon count)

- Assign the textures to the objects -
- And all to the highest resolution object as LOD objects.
- Adjust the distance for where they should be displayed.
- Move all but the highest resolution object to an invisble layer.

The effect is visible in the viewport:

[image]

A python soultion would be to combine snippets from:

- [Python - Set material to material slot](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8475/python-set-material-to-material-slot)
- [How to get the distance between two objects in the game engine?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7144/how-to-get-the-distance-between-two-objects-in-the-game-engine)

Comment: Thanks but i want it to be done in/by python script. Not by changing objects.

Comment: @EwwGin I just linked two posts containing the snippets you need.

Comment: Umm. i need it ( changing materials ) to happen in bge / while >game< is running. if possible.